# How to use a different version of python duing NPM install?

Tags: centos, python, centos5, node.js, npm

Salam (means Hello) :)

I have terminal access to a VPS running centos 5.9 and default python 2.4.3 installed. I also installed python 2.7.3 via these commands: (I used `make altinstall` instead of `make install`)

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
tar -xf Python-2.7.3.tgz
cd Python-2.7.3
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

then I installed node.js from source via these commands:

```
python2.7 ./configure
make
make install
```

The problem is, when I use `npm install` and try to install a node.js package which requires python > 2.4.3 I get this error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v2.4.3, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:125:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:114:9
```

how should I *"pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wa Alikom Al Salam Nasser  =)

If you have python2.7 in your $PATH and you can issue it directly from the command like '$ python 2.7', try putting it as an argument for --python:

```
$ npm --python python2.7 install
```

If it didn't work try using the full path to python2.7

```
$ npm --python /usr/bin/python2.7 install
```

Comment: I had to add an `=` to get it to work: `npm --python=python2.7 install`